# When we connect to specific wifi on android 10 then internet not running while internet is available in router

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am working on Xamarin android platform and after android 10 update "Automatically connect to wifi through code" has stopped.So after using android 10 code of wifi through request worked successfully and my problem is after wifi connection Internet not working on my phone. If we connect to that network manually then everything is fine.So I have tried two solution for that:

1) If we remove this line RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Internet) then wifi connected successfully but internet not working.
2) if we add AddCapability(NetCapability.Internet) option then request popup not occured and wifi not connected.

So please look into this.

**1) I want to connect to wifi through code in android 10 using xamarin.

2) The part i have done is connection to wifi is completed.

3) Problem i have faced is after connection internet is not working.**

If i am connecting to wifi manully then internet working

```
try
                {
                    var connectivityManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService) as ConnectivityManager;
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
                    if (!wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
                    {
                        Forms.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWifiSettings));
                        return false;
                    }

                    var callback = new NetworkCallback(connectivityManager)
                    {
                        NetworkAvailable = network =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                            MessagingCenter.Send<string, Boolean>("ConnectModel", "connecttowifi", true);
                        },
                        NetworkUnavailable = () =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Not Connected");
                            MessagingCenter.Send<string, Boolean>("ConnectModel", "connecttowifi", false);
                        }
                    };
                    var specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .SetSsid(ssid)
                    .SetWpa2Passphrase(password)
                    .Build();
                    var request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                        .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi)
                        //.AddCapability(NetCapability.Internet)
                        //.RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Internet)
                        .SetNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                        .Build();
                    connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, callback);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Write(e.Message);
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you've done ，what you want to do, and hopefully show us some codes

Comment: 1) I want to connect to wifi through code in android 10 using xamarin.                              2) Connect to wifi part through code is successfully done                                                     3) But problem is that after connecting to wifi internet is not working.                                                                                                                                                                          code is attached above.

Comment: @kefiKefi  do you find any solution?